# Python - Sum with Start

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

```
>>> sum([1,2,3])
6
```

Failed attempt to declare start position:

```
>>> sum([1,2,3],1)
7
```

---

Docs say `sum(iterable[, start])`

Can someone supply me with an example of using sum declaring start position please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *start* means the sum starting value, not the position on the array:

[sum()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=built%20functions#sum):

> Sums *start* and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total.

If you want to accomplish that you can use list slicing:

```
>>>sum([1,2,3][1:])
5
```

This slicing won't work with an iterator, in that case you can use `enumerate()` in a generator expression. Something like this:

```
>>> i=iter([1,2,3])
>>> sum(v for i,v in enumerate(i) if i >= 1)
5
```

Or better yet as pointed out by @lvc on the comments, use the [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.islice) function to slice the iterator:

```
>>>import itertools
>>> i=iter([1,2,3])
>>> sum(itertools.islice(i,1,None))
5
```

Comment: Or use itertools: `sum(islice(i, 1, None))`

Comment: @lvc I was sure! it was a better way in that case. Thank you very much for pointing out :)